Functions differentiable at a point from everywhere continuous nowhere differentiable functions
I'm looking at an example about functions that are differentiable at a single point, and it starts with an everywhere continuous nowhere differentiable function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which is used to define $f(x)=xg(x)$.  The derivative of $f$ is then simply
$$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=x\frac{g(y)-g(x)}{y-x}+g(y)$$
Now, at $x=0$ I fully understand why the derivative exists, but in the book they say that for non-zero $x$,

f'(x) does not exist, since $g(y)\rightarrow g(x)$ an $g'(x)$ does not exist

I'm a bit confused by the first part, since surely if $g'(x)$ DNE that automatically disqualifies the existence of $f'(x)$ no?  What purpose does $g(y)\rightarrow g(x)$ serve?

If $x\neq 0$ "linearity of limits" applies.

The equations you have given for the derivative of $f$ are missing some limiting processes (maybe $\lim_{y \to x}$ on all sides). The bit you quote about $f(x)$ existing also seems to be wrong: clearly $f(x)$ does exist.

I will first write down the proof again in order to better show the critical point:
Assume $f$ is differentiable in $x\neq0$, i.e. the limit \begin{equation}\lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=\lim_{y\to x}\left(x\frac{g(x)-g(y)}{x-y}+g(y)\right)\label{gl1}\tag1\end{equation} exists. Since $g$ is continuous everywhere, i.e. in particular in $x$, \begin{equation}\lim_{y\to x}g(y)=g(x)\label{gl2}\tag2\end{equation} applies. We would now like to use the following limit theorem:
Let $f_1,f_2\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be two functions and $x\in \mathbb R$. If $\lim_{y\to x}f_1(x)$ and $\lim_{y\to x}f_2(x)$ exist, so does $$\lim_{y\to x}(f_1(x)\pm f_2(x)).$$
So if we apply this to \eqref{gl1} and \eqref{gl2}, we get
$$\lim_{y\to x}\left(x\frac{g(x)-g(y)}{x-y}+g(y)\right)-\lim_{y\to x}g(y)=\lim_{y\to x}\left(x\frac{g(x)-g(y)}{x-y}+g(y)-g(y)\right)=x\cdot \lim_{y\to x}\left(\frac{g(x)-g(y)}{x-y}\right).$$
However, the right-hand limit now corresponds to the $x$-fold differential quotient of $g$ in $x$, which does not exist according to the assumption (since $x\neq0$). Contradiction therefore $f$ is not differentiable in $x\neq0$. $\square$
If the limit $\lim_{y\to x}g(y)$ did not exist, we could not use the above limit theorem, because in general the convergence of $\lim_{y\to x}(f_1(y)+f_2(y))$ does not imply the convergence of $\lim_{y\to x}f_2(y)$. As an example, choose any function $f_1$ for which $\lim_{y\to x}f_1(y)$ does not exist and define $f_2:=-f_1$.
